# ' Unable to download all specified images.' when trying to run a notification on a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

**Script:**

```js
 chrome.notifications.create(
    'name-for-notification',{   
    type: 'basic', 
    iconUrl: 'icon4.png',
    title: "This is a notification", 
    message: "hello there!" 
    });
```

Everytime I run it, I get the error

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running notifications.create: Unable to download all specified images.

But here's the thing, "icon4.png" is in the same file as my script, background. 
[See for yourself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh61D.png)

I don't know why it's not working, the icon is there. I've tried using this aswell:

```js
 chrome.notifications.create(
        'name-for-notification',{   
        type: 'basic', 
        iconUrl: 'http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/671921/icon4.png',
        title: "This is a notification", 
        message: "hello there!" 
        });
```

And it still doesnt work!

And yes, I have the notifications permission set in my manifest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### URLs must be relative to your *manifest.json* (first code block)

Your issue is that you have not provided Chrome with a URL that provides the `iconUrl` as a URL relative to your *manifest.json*. [The `iconUrl` documentation states](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#property-NotificationOptions-iconUrl) [emphasis mine]:

> URLs can be a data URL, a blob URL, or a **URL relative to a resource within this extension's .crx file**

You appear to have provided a URL that is relative to the location of your *background.js* script, not relative to your *manifest.json*. This can be determined by the fact that your *manifest.json* is not in the same directory as your *background.js*. Without you providing your *manifest.json* it's not possible to tell you exactly what this URL must be. However, it needs to be a path relative to your *manifest.json* file, similar to how you have referenced your *bakground.js*.

### External URLs are not permitted (second code block)

The `iconUrl` you have provided is not permitted. The permitted types of URLs are [clearly listed in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#property-NotificationOptions-iconUrl) (see quote above). Effectively, the restriction is that the data for the icon must be supplied completely from within the extension. You can not have Chrome fetch the data for the icon from the network by just passing an external URL for `iconUrl`. That does not mean that you must include the icon data (e.g. *icon4.png*) in your extension's *.crx* file. You could fetch the data yourself; convert it to a data URL or blob URL; then provide it to Chrome. But, the data must already exist in your extension.

Comment: In most cases an external URL works. I don't figure out why, but replacing an external URL with an internal one fixed an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Makyen, here's an example I've used in my extensions. First fetch the image blob, then convert it to an URL:

```
const response = await fetch('https://yourexternalimageurl.com/image.jpg');
const blob = await response.blob();

const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

chrome.notifications.create(null, {
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: url,
    title: 'Title',
    message: 'Message',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but here's the quickest way to fix this. Use the `chrome.runtime.getURL()` function for assets inside of the extension, such as icons.

```
 chrome.notifications.create(
    'name-for-notification',{   
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('icon4.png'), // --HERE--
    title: "This is a notification", 
    message: "hello there!" 
    });
```